# I am not able to resolve the RecursionError from Django framework

Tags: python, django

`python manage.py runserver` throws exception. How do I get my launch webpage on localhost?

I have tried Django Slack community group and also tried StackOverflow question regarding "RecursionError" in Django Framework, but the answers are uncertain and confusing.

python3 manage.py runserver
 Performing system checks...

```
Unhandled exception in thread started by <function check_errors.<locals>.wrapper at 0x102b926a8>
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/Users/kuldeep/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 225, in wrapper fn(*args, **kwargs)
File "/Users/kuldeep/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 117, in inner_run            self.check(display_num_errors=True)
File "/Users/kuldeep/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 379, in check
        include_deployment_checks=include_deployment_checks,
File "/Users/kuldeep/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 366, in _run_checks
        return checks.run_checks(**kwargs)
File "/Users/kuldeep/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/checks/registry.py", line 71, in run_checks
        new_errors = check(app_configs=app_configs)
File "/Users/kuldeep/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/checks/urls.py", line 40, in check_url_namespaces_unique
        all_namespaces = _load_all_namespaces(resolver)
File "/Users/kuldeep/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/checks/urls.py", line 67, in _load_all_namespaces
        namespaces.extend(_load_all_namespaces(pattern, current))
File "/Users/kuldeep/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/checks/urls.py", line 67, in _load_all_namespaces
        namespaces.extend(_load_all_namespaces(pattern, current))
File "/Users/kuldeep/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/checks/urls.py", line 67, in _load_all_namespaces
        namespaces.extend(_load_all_namespaces(pattern, current))
      [Previous line repeated 986 more times]
File "/Users/kuldeep/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/checks/urls.py", line 59, in _load_all_namespaces
        ':'.join(parents + (url.namespace,)) for url in url_patterns
File "/Users/kuldeep/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/checks/urls.py", line 60, in <listcomp>
        if getattr(url, 'namespace', None) is not None
    RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object
```

I am expecting the flying rocket which gives me confidence of congratulation message on my localhost.

mysite/urls.py file:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import include, path

urlpatterns = [
    path('polls/', include('polls.urls')),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
]
```

polls/urls.py file:

```
from django.urls import include, path
from django.contrib import admin
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('polls/', include ('polls.urls')),
    path ('admin/', admin.site.urls),
]
```

polls/views.py code:

```
from django.shortcuts import render

# Create your views here.
from django.http import HttpResponse

def index(request):
  return HttpResponse("Hello, world. You are at the polls index")
```

Comment: you probably have a loop in your url patterns (two files loading each other). Check your *urls.py* files or show them to us here.

Comment: Here is my mysite/urls.py file:

""mysite URL Configuration

from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import include, path

urlpatterns = [
    path('polls/', include('polls.urls')),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
]

Comment: please embed it in your question, not in the comments. And show the *polls.urls* file as well

Comment: @dirkgroten thanks. put my urls.py file with question.

Comment: can you please add your `poll`'s view code too.

Comment: your *polls/urls.py* `urlpatterns` is including itself. It shouldn't contain the paths "polls/" and "admin/" but the sub-paths to your specific polls views. E.g. `path('', views.index)`

Comment: you most create a viwe in views.py file after that import Views , and app_na in urls.py file

Answer (score 3):

Look at your *polls/urls.py* code for `urlpatterns`, it's including itself, which causes an endless loop.

Your *polls/urls.py* should contain the sub-paths specific for the *polls* app. Since this app has just one view, you probably just want one path:

```
path('', views.index)
```

Remember, this is included by *my_site/urls.py* under the `polls/` path, so the full path to get the `index` view will be: "/polls/".

You're probably doing the Django tutorial, check you code [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/intro/tutorial01/#write-your-first-view)