# Django urls.py: RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object

Tags: python, django, django-urls

I want to make a urls that leads to my urls.py in my app, but it gives me a RecursionError every time.
This is my code:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('shop/', include('ptr.urls'))
]
```

And if you need the full traceback, here it is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/threading.py", line 1009, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/threading.py", line 946, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 64, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 134, in inner_run
    self.check(display_num_errors=True)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 475, in check
    all_issues = checks.run_checks(
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/checks/registry.py", line 88, in run_checks
    new_errors = check(app_configs=app_configs, databases=databases)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/checks/urls.py", line 42, in check_url_namespaces_unique
    all_namespaces = _load_all_namespaces(resolver)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/checks/urls.py", line 72, in _load_all_namespaces
    namespaces.extend(_load_all_namespaces(pattern, current))
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/checks/urls.py", line 72, in _load_all_namespaces
    namespaces.extend(_load_all_namespaces(pattern, current))
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/checks/urls.py", line 72, in _load_all_namespaces
    namespaces.extend(_load_all_namespaces(pattern, current))
  [Previous line repeated 987 more times]
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/checks/urls.py", line 62, in _load_all_namespaces
    namespaces = [
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/checks/urls.py", line 65, in <listcomp>
    if getattr(url, "namespace", None) is not None
RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object
```

Comment: Can you provide the ptr.urls module?

Comment: Possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54676634/i-am-not-able-to-resolve-the-recursionerror-from-django-framework